# listview setonitemclicklistener with arrayadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapterview

When try tu add method setOnItemClikListener show me this error: setOnItemClikListener (ItemClikListener) in AdapterView cannot be applied to ().

My code is:

```
List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
    mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,weekForecast);

    ListView listViewForecast = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listViewForecast.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
    listViewForecast.setOnItemClickListener();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following :

```
List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

    mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item1,weekForecast);

    ListView listViewForecast = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listViewForecast.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

    listViewForecast.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                      int position, long id) {
                       //Do your thing here

                  }
                });
```

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: thanks it works now!!!